# MeanJs: How to POST data? Why the service actions does not triggering?

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs

I am new to angular and express, MeanJs so need help. What I am doing wrong, how to post data  and get answer?
I want to execute Complile function and pass the code from text box to server and do something with it and get answer. 
But how to write code in lab.client.service.js or others files?
Becouse I do not get any information that starting from file [3] the code were executed.
I wrote this code using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOqLbJTvCv8&feature=youtu.be tutorial.

**Files**

1. **lab.client.view.html** I have text box with binds to data.code angular object

   ```
   <textarea ng-model="data.code"></textarea>
   ```

and have two buttons with trigers functions in :

```
<div style="margin:12px;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="LabController.compile()">Compile</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="LabController.compileAndUpload()">Cimpile & Upload</button>
</div>
```

2. **lab.client.controller.js**

   ```
   'use strict';

   angular.module('core').controller('LabController', ['$scope', 'Lab',
   function($scope, Lab) {
       $scope.data = {
           code: ''
       };

       this.compile = function() {
                   console.log('User clicked compile', $scope.data.code);       //This message is printed in browser console.
           $scope.message = Lab.compile                                   //But this action does not executes???
       };

       this.compileAndUpload = function() {
                    console.log('User clicked compileAndUpload', $scope.data.code);    //This message is printed in browser console.
            $scope.message = Lab.compileAndUpload;             //But this action does not executes???
       };
   }
   ]);
   ```
3. **lab.client.service.js**

   ```
   'use strict';

   angular.module('core').factory('Lab', ['$resource', function($resource) {
       console.info("client.service: Veikia!");
       return $resource('lab', {                           
           compile: {                     //I do not see that there URL were triggered
               method: 'POST',
               url: '/lab/compile'  
           },
           compileAndUpload: {   //I do not see that there URL were triggered
               method: 'POST',
               url: '/lab/compileAndUpload',               
           }
       });
   }
   ]);
   ```
4. **lab.server.routes.js**

   ```
   'use strict';

   module.exports = function(app) {
   var lab = require('../../app/controllers/lab.server.controller');

   // Lab Routes
   app.route('/lab/compile')
       .post(lab.compile);

   app.route('/lab/compileAndUpload')
       .post(lab.compileAndUpload);
   };
   ```
5. **lab.server.controller.js**

   ```
   'use strict';

   var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
   _ = require('lodash');

   var response = {
   'message' : 'It works'
   };

   exports.compile = function(req, res) {
   var code = req.body.data.code;
   res.jsonp(response);
   };

   exports.compileAndUpload = function(req, res) { 
       var code = req.body.data.code; 
   res.jsonp(response);
   };
   ```

Comment: call the compile function not assign the function `$scope.message = Lab.compile()` ,

Comment: I tried this. Then I get error when click button:
        TypeError: Lab.compile is not a function
    at compile (lab.client.controller.js:12)
    at Parser.functionCall (angular.js:10903)
    at angular-touch.js:441
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12909)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular-touch.js:440)
    at angular.js:2853
    at forEach (angular.js:325)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:2852)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues with the code:

1. Incorrectly defined custom resource actions. See the [argument list](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). 2nd argument is for default Parameters:

   ```
   return $resource('lab', {}, {  // <-- 3rd argument                          
    compile: {                     
       method: 'POST',
       url: '/lab/compile'  
    },
    compileAndUpload: {
       method: 'POST',
       url: '/lab/compileAndUpload',               
    }
   });
   ```
2. In `$scope.message = Lab.compile` you are assigning the action instead of invoking it:

   ```
   this.compile = function() {
        console.log('User clicked compile', $scope.data.code);       //This message is printed in browser console.
        $scope.message = Lab.compile() // <-- invoke
   };

   this.compileAndUpload = function() {
        console.log('User clicked compileAndUpload', $scope.data.code);    //This message is printed in browser console.
        $scope.message = Lab.compileAndUpload();
   };
   ```

Comment: Hello, thanks, I acceot is as ansver as the request started working. Only one question.... How need to pass the text from the textBox to server in these "compile" and  "compileAndUpload" actions?

Comment: Please check the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), there is some examples on how to post data.